# ERROR_RUNNING_JOB with 32 qubit circuit running on ibmq_qasm_simulator backend

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

I recently made a quantum circuit that uses 32 qubits and try to run it on 
IBM Q Experience *qasm_simulator* backend. But it always ends with `ERROR_RUNNING_JOB`.

When i retrieve the job and display the error, i only got

> "The following experiments failed:\n"
>   without any details.

How i can get more information about the error?

The following is my qiskit version information:

```
{'qiskit': None, 'qiskit-terra': '0.8.0', 'qiskit-ignis': '0.1.1', 'qiskit-aer': '0.2.0', 'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.2.2', 'qiskit-aqua': '0.5.2'}
```

According to @Bram suggestion i run

```
$ pip install qiskit
Building wheels for collected packages: qiskit, qiskit-ibmq-provider
  Building wheel for qiskit (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command /home/userName/anaconda3/envs/quantum/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-kavivdyx/qiskit/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-eak_06_d --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for qiskit
  Running setup.py clean for qiskit
  Building wheel for qiskit-ibmq-provider (setup.py) ... done
  Stored in directory: /home/userName/.cache/pip/wheels/0c/56/e7/b07b4d2f19fd4c5fff7fe334c72eb313fecf04fa693a7c558e
Successfully built qiskit-ibmq-provider
Failed to build qiskit
Installing collected packages: qiskit-terra, qiskit-aer, nest-asyncio, qiskit-ibmq-provider, pyscf, qiskit-chemistry, qiskit, more-itertools
  Found existing installation: qiskit-terra 0.8.0
    Uninstalling qiskit-terra-0.8.0:
      Successfully uninstalled qiskit-terra-0.8.0
  Found existing installation: qiskit-aer 0.2.0
    Uninstalling qiskit-aer-0.2.0:
      Successfully uninstalled qiskit-aer-0.2.0
  Found existing installation: qiskit-ibmq-provider 0.2.2
    Uninstalling qiskit-ibmq-provider-0.2.2:
      Successfully uninstalled qiskit-ibmq-provider-0.2.2
  Running setup.py install for qiskit ... done
  Found existing installation: more-itertools 6.0.0
    Uninstalling more-itertools-6.0.0:
      Successfully uninstalled more-itertools-6.0.0
Successfully installed more-itertools-5.0.0 nest-asyncio-1.0.0 pyscf-1.6.2 qiskit-0.11.0 qiskit-aer-0.2.3 qiskit-chemistry-0.5.0 qiskit-ibmq-provider-0.3.0 qiskit-terra-0.8.2
```

From this output i notice that `wheel` was failed in build, does that cause any problems?

I then run

```
$conda list | grep qiskit
qiskit                    0.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
qiskit-aer                0.2.3                    pypi_0    pypi
qiskit-aqua               0.5.2                    pypi_0    pypi
qiskit-chemistry          0.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
qiskit-ibmq-provider      0.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
qiskit-ignis              0.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
qiskit-terra              0.8.2                    pypi_0    pypi
enter preformatted text here
```

and run the following in IPython console

```
>>import qiskit
>>qiskit.__qiskit_version__
Out[2]: 
{'qiskit': '0.11.0',
 'qiskit-terra': '0.8.2',
 'qiskit-ignis': '0.1.1',
 'qiskit-aer': '0.2.3',
 'qiskit-ibmq-provider': '0.3.0',
 'qiskit-aqua': '0.5.2'}
```

i will send another job and wait for the result.

Edit: 
The same error , ERROR_RUNNING_JOB, still occur, appear after the above update.

Comment: Installation is fine, wheel failure is not an problem, Did you try another standard example? ERROR_RUNNING_JOB could also mean a wrong line in youre code. Also the credentials needs to be set.

Comment: @Bram If you mean IBMQ credentials of course i set them. I tried a smaller circuit with 28 qubit and it works without errors. The 32 qubit circuit use another subcircuit that is tested and used in the 28 quibt circuit.

Comment: Hi, can you provide some more information about the circuit you are running and the parameters you are using to submit it?

Answer (score 1):

You're qiskit information shows 'qiskit': None. This should be 0.11 or smaller. Furthermore qiskit-ibmq-provider : 0.2.2 should be 0.3 for the latest version.